# Is there a better way to write this filter function?

Tags: ocaml, boolean-logic, higher-order-functions

I am supposed to create a function what takes a list and a range and filter the list to be within that range of numbers. Here is what I have so far:

```
let filter_range (nums : int list) (range : int * int) : int list =
  match range with
  | (a, b) -> if a > b then []
    else List.filter (fun (x : int) -> 
    if a <= x && x <= b then true else false) nums ;;
```

I feel like this could be much cleaner, any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
let filter_range nums (lo, hi) =
  List.filter (fun x -> lo <= x && x <= hi) nums
```